# Laravel 6 - Affiliate Tracking User Registeration

Tags: php, laravel, affiliate

[image]

As u guys can see in `Image Above`, i want to create referral_system that user can register and input `referral_user` from `affiliate users`.

And **`Referral_Code`** is unique for every user.

**`My Problem is I cant track Whom that code is.`**

**`My User Schema`**

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('referrer_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('referrer_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('referral_code')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('referred_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**`My User Model`**

```
    public function referrer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    public function referrals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

**`In My UserController`**

```
       $referrer = User::where('name', auth()->user()->name)->first();

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->referral_code = substr(uniqid(), 0, 8); // for unique id
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->referrer_id = $referrer ? $referrer->id : null;
        $user->role = $request->role;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
            'created' => true,
        ]);
```

Hope u guys will give me some idea and if u notice mistake in my code, pls correct me, I'll appreciate of all ur help.

Thanks...

Comment: What errors do you receive on screen?

Comment: My problem is, when user inputed the code, i cant track that code whom is that code... @user8555937

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're confusing Laravel relationships. `hasOne, belongsTo, etc` are not designed to be worked with in the same model. Basically what you're saying in `Users` model is that "User has a User where user_id = id" which makes no sense.

I have no idea how you've designed your sql tables, I recommend you to split your entities in distinct parts and have pivot tables which binds them: `users, affiliates, referrals`

```
- users table have     : "id"
- affiliates table have: "id", "refferal_code"
- refferals table have : "id", "affiliate_id", "user_id", "refferal_code"
```

You tie a user with an affiliate through `refferals` table, through their IDs.

Then create relationships between those. You may want to read more about [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) as well. Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: i saw someone build it and use the same model and i cloned his project and its work fine. since i work with `nuxtjs` for `fronend` its not work as i want..

Comment: `here the link` https://dev.to/simioluwatomi/let-s-build-a-super-simple-referral-system-with-laravel-1o3h